# Furthest location in matrix with certain value

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Lets say I have a binary matrix, how do I find the `(row,col)` location of the furthest north, south, east, and west with a value of `1` (or `0`).

Can this be easily transferred to finding the same furthest regions with a specific value in non binary matrices?

Comment: Furthest from where? From the center of matrix maybe?

Comment: Furthest north = most northerly point (regardless of east or west) where there is a 1 or 0.

Furthest south = most southerly point (regardless of east or west) where there is a 1 or 0.

Furthest east = most easterly point (regardless of north or south) where there is a 1 or 0.

Furthest west = most westerly point (regardless of north or south) where there is a 1 or 0.

Comment: We could have multiple up "north" ones at the same row. So, which one?

Comment: Oh sorry, from the (0,0) position.

Comment: And what about for `south, east, and west `. What anchor points do we have for those rest of three cases?

Comment: You'd just iterate through the matrix, wouldn't you? You can have a quick hack to calculate just how far north or how far east a point is, and just keep the maximal points for those.

Comment: Ok, maybe I didn't think this through properly. As I didn't think about there being multiple locations. How about, the most northerly / southerly row, or easterly / westerly column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just look up the indices of any column or row that has a `True` in it.

```
NS = np.where(np.any(M, axis=0))[0]
WE = np.where(np.any(M, axis=1))[0]
```

Take the first and last to get the extents:

```
N = NS[0]
S = NS[-1]
W = WE[0]
E = WE[-1]
```

For a non-boolean matrix `M` you'd need to do some comparison that will output a boolean matrix, like:

```
NS = np.where(np.any(M > 0, axis=0))[0]
WE = np.where(np.any(M > 0, axis=1))[0]
```